# Does document.write remove css styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to run the script without removing CSS styling.

For example, here I want the background to be blue still when the random number shows.

```js
function myFunc() {
  document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 999));
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()">Get random num</button>
```

Comment: Yes, if used like that, document.write() clears the entire document. Which is the primary reason not to use it. Add an output element like `<pre id="output"></pre>`, then use `document.getElementById('output').innerText = x;` instead

Answer (score 0):

Put value inside of another element instead of making new document.

Try:

```
let s = document.createElement("span");
s.innerHtml = Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
body.appendChild(s);
```

Edit:
I didn't see that @Chris G answered your question but here is a bit different approach with generating new element for each random instead of replacing it. I guess his answer suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

that is not a good practice

You can try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>
    body{
  background-color: blue;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="text"> </p>
  <button onclick="myFunc()">Get random num</button>
  <script>

     function myFunc(){
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML=( Math.floor(Math.random()*999));
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're talking about good practice (and you are right, document.write is _not_ good practice) it is better practice to use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML` if you are not adding any markup, like in your case. Incidentally, your color choices are unreadable. How about `background-color: wheat;`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Once you click on the button then your html code changes to:

```
<html><head></head><body>934</body></html>
```

It is removing the style as well.

As per [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. This is because `document.write()` is overwriting all `style` and `link` elements that may be present in the document. `document.write()` completely overwrites *everything* in the document.

Example:

```js
function doIt() {
  document.write('text')
  
  doSomethingElse() // Will not get executed since the script tags have been removed
}
```

```html
<button onclick='doIt()'>Use document.write</button>
```